# youtube api - get videos ordered by their views

Tags: youtube-api

I would like to get a list of the X most popular vidoes on youtube. The 'most_viewed' flag isn't good enough at it doesn't give me the ability to page the results. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tell what language you are in, but I've achieved this in PHP like this:

```
$query = $yt->newVideoQuery();
$query->setVideoQuery('');
$query->setOrderBy('viewCount');
$feed = $yt->getVideoFeed($query->getQueryUrl(2));
```

I have not tried this, but the docs say:

```
$query->setMaxResults(5); //Sets the max results per query
$query->setStartIndex(2); //Paging
```

See the [docs](http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Searching_for_Videos) for more detailed information.